# How to target the elements inside a pseudo-element SVG

Tags: css, svg

Is it possible for CSS to target the internal layers of an SVG inserted as the `background-image` of a pseudo-element?

---

I have a custom CSS for a website whose layout I don't control, such that I cannot insert the image directly as `<svg>` into the HTML, I have to insert it as a pseudo-element, `::before` , as `background-image` .   It gets displayed fine. Then I want to style its layers for colors and some animation:

```
CircleButton
  Bullet
  Ring
```

These are names I specified in Illustrator. They should theoretically become targettable `id` : "CircleButton" for the svg itself, "Bullet" and "Ring" for the two internal layers. I tried to target them in Stylus as:

```
#CircleButton
  #Bullet
    fill: orange
  #Ring
    stroke: blue
```

It didn't work.

Checking the inspector, none of these layers' names are there, it says just `::before`.

Are the layers really untargettable, or is there a workaround?

Comment: No, you can not target elements within your SVG, when it is embedded as a background image (or via `img`/`object`.) You can only do that, if the SVG is part of your document itself to begin with.